# Yii-Model-Relations queried with LEFT OUTER JOIN with multiple user permissions

Tags: php, join, user-permissions, yii

I'm using the Yii-Framework and I want to make it more secure:
Models with sensitive data like user data should use an own MySQL-user that has only the permissions for this table. Models with data that aren't sensitive can use a default user which has no permissions for the user-table.

**Example:**
Table "post" has following fields: "id", "author", "title" and "content"
Table "users" has following fields: "id", "username", "pwhash", "email"

It's pretty easy to implement that, just override the *getDbConnection()* in the user-model with a second db-connection specified in the config file with the privilege to access the user-table.

My problem is that when a model has relations with the user-table (e.g. post has the field author which is linked to the user-table) Yii is building a join-query which is trying to access the user-table with lower privileges.

Easy solution is to give the post model a db-connection that can access both tables but in this case the security is gone.
Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an "external" API level that deals with the correct permissions for you.

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/activeresource

Comment: Thank you for your Answer!
But I think that this extension is not the right choice for me.
I have already a very big codebase with different projects and for that little security improvement change everything and build an API for every project is just too much.
Do you may have another idea? Maybe try to prevent the JOINs and get all relations seperatly?